# INotifyPropertyChanged for indexed properties

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, inotifypropertychanged

So I have a class as follows:

```
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public object this[string field]
    {
        get => // gets the value
        set
        {
            // sets the value
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        }
    }
}
```

and in my view :

```
<DataGrid
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="[some_field]" Binding="{Binding Path=[some_field]}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="[some_other_field]" Binding="{Binding Path=[some_other_field]}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This works fine but when `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));` happens, the `DataGrid` will fetch both the field `"some_field"` and the field `"some_other_field"` in `Data` and I haven't found a way to use the `PropertyChanged` that would make it refresh only the field that was updated.

I've tried with `"Item[" + field + "]"`, `"[" + field + "]"`, `field` but no luck. Is this something that is possible/supported or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible, at least for WPF and dot NET Framework.

Suggestion/workaround: What if we added some read-only properties to the view model?
Example:

```
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public object this[string field]
    {
        get => // gets the value
        set
        {
            // sets the value
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(field));
        }
    }

    public object some_field => this[nameof(some_field)];
    public object some_other_field=> this[nameof(some_other_field)];
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<DataGrid
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="[some_field]" Binding="{Binding Path=some_field}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="[some_other_field]" Binding="{Binding Path=some_other_field}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Doesn't really answer your question specifically, but it does provide a way to control how much of the view gets refreshed.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be another way because I cannot add fields to the Data class. However it seems to be not supported at the moment :-(

Comment: Sorry, if I misunderstood. You mentioned that you can change the code in `Data.this[string field] set { ... }` to call PropertyChanged event with various strings,
but cannot add new properties to that same class? (I assumed you meant properties instead of fields). How so?